# jquery action on submit button if form correct

Tags: jquery

I have a form in an iframe and am trying to close the iframe with a jquery click function but ONLY if the form is submitted correctly - the form is part of a wordpress plugin (User Meta Pro) and has validation - does not send the form if user details incorrect. I cannot override the form target (to parent) for some reason so have to try this way. My attempted code (in document ready) is:

```
$(".um_login_button").click(function(){
parent.$.fancybox.close();
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code, perhaps try this?

```
window.top.$.fancybox.close();
```

Comment: Same thing - when the button is clicked it straight away closes - I need some kind of check on the form behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Oh so I interpreted your question, you would need to find the js in the code(I'm guessing it is doing ajax calls and then add your own code if in the success part, because even doing something like: $("#form_submit").submit(); would not work since you have no way of inferring whether it was a success or not with out access to anything.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I have put form in a div rather than iframe!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using a div on same page as parent.